# Visual Studio Code - Put User Snippets above Emmet Snippets?

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

Is there a way to have user snippets appear above emmet snippets in the suggestions dropdown?

At present my snippet for the same abbreviation as an emmet snippet will appear second in the drop down. I would like to simply press enter to accept my snippet and not have to press down arrow first.

I have this in my settings but it doesn't help:

```json
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
```

The reason for using user snippets for customization is that, while I know how to customize emmet snippets, the more restricted syntax in customizing emmet snippets doesn't allow me to create the snippet I need, while regular user snippets will allow it.

Comment: Does disabling (false is the default) `Emmet: Show Suggestions as Snippets` do what you want.?  Then with `editor.snippetSuggestions: top` should put the emmet suggestions lower than other snippet suggestions.

Comment: @Mark Thanks, that worked perfectly! If you would like to post that as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can lower the priority of emmet suggestions with a combination of settings:

`editor.snippetSuggestions: top`  (`Editor: Snippet Suggestions`) will put snippets as the top suggestions, so that you may be able to accept the top suggestion being one of your custom snippets.

and

disabling `Emmet: Show Suggestions as Snippets` will prevent emmet suggestions from appearing with the same priority as your other snippets.